# Celery result, get not working

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am using 2 celery instances.

The configuration of the first instance is:

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='amqp',
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=18000,
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',

    CELERY_ROUTES={
        'task_polling': {
            'queue': 'task_polling_queue'
        },
        'save_shell_task': {
            'queue': 'save_shell_task_queue'
        },
        'save_validation_chain_task': {
            'queue': 'save_validation_chain_task_queue'
        },
        'do_work': {
            'queue': 'do_work_queue'
        },
        'send_mail': {
            'queue': 'send_mail_queue'
        }
    },
)

@shared_task(name='do_work', ignore_result=True)
def do_work(_serialized_task):
    for bla in blala:
        do_something()  
        is_canceled = send_task('save_validation_chain_task', [], 
                                {'_params': my_params}).get() == True
```

Launched with the following command:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info -Q do_work_queue,send_mail_queue
```

and the second one:

```
app = Celery()

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='amqp',
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=18000,
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER ='json',
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE={
        'periodic_task': {
            'task': 'task_polling',
            'schedule': timedelta(seconds=1),
        },
    },
    CELERY_ROUTES={
        'task_polling': {
            'queue': 'task_polling_queue'
        },
        'save_shell_task': {
            'queue': 'save_shell_task_queue'
        },
        'save_validation_chain_task': {
            'queue': 'save_validation_chain_task_queue'
        },
        'do_work': {
            'queue': 'do_work_queue'
        },
        'send_mail': {
            'queue': 'send_mail_queue'
        }
    },
)


@shared_task(name='save_shell_task', ignore_result=True)
def save_shell_task(_result):
    ShellUpdate(_json_result=_result).to_db()


@shared_task(name='save_validation_chain_task', ignore_result=False)
def save_validation_chain_task(_result):
    return ValidationChainUpdate(_json_result=_result).to_db()
```

This one is launched with:

```
celery -A my_prog worker -B --concurrency=1 -P processes -Q task_polling_queue,save_shell_task_queue,save_validation_chain_task_queue
```

The issue is that the `send_task(...).get()` is not receiving the result. The program is waiting in a loop.

It seems that celery doesn't received the queue result or doesn't waiting the right queue result. The issue is certainly due to the -Q parameter. Do you have any idea where could be the issue in the configuration?

thank you

EDIT:
The global idea is to have two celery instances with different source codes. That why I decided to enumerate the queues to remove the dependency. I really think this is why the result is not consumed as I can't specify the queue result in the command as this one has a variable name for each result (queue created for each result dynamically by celery). Any solution to keep two different source codes for the celery instance is good for me. I would like to avoid to use another result backend as the volumetric is very low.

Comment: Just out of curiosity if you did `'my_prog.save_validation_chain_task_queue'` instead of just `'save_validation_chain_task_queue'`

Comment: I corrected the call. It was `save_validation_chain_task`. The worker is well called but the result is not received. If I had the namespace my_prog, the worker is not called at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have correct setup and config. The only problem is you have set `ignore_result` for `do_work` task.

```
@shared_task(name='do_work', ignore_result=True)
```

When set this, even though your task is completed by the worker the `state` of the task will be always `PENDING`. Thats why when you are doing a `.get()` on that task, it never completes the execution of the that statement.

Since you  are accepting only `json`

```
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER ='json',
```

you also need to set

```
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json',
```

in both of your configs.

**Note:**

In your case, your are doing a `.get()` on a task INSIDE another task. This should be avoided. For now it will work fine. From [celery 3.2 it will raise and error instead of warining](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-synchronous-subtasks).

You can use [chain](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains) to prevent launching synchronous subtasks if they fit your need. When chain is  called, it returns async_result object which has parent property. For example

```
task1 = add.s(1,2)
task2 = add.s(5)
task3 = add.s(10)

result = chain(task1 | task2 | task3)()

result.revoke(terminate=True)                 # revokes task3
result.parent.revoke(terminate=True)          # revokes task2
result.parent.parent.revoke(terminate=True)   # revokes task1
```

If they don't fit, you can use signals to call some other tasks/functions. Here is a simple example(I have not tested this code).

```
from celery.signals import task_success

@app.task
def small_task():
      print('small task completed')


@app.task
@task_success.connect(sender=small_task)
def big_task(**kwargs):
      print('called by small_task. LOL {0}'.format(kwargs))
```

Comment: The `CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER` setting fixed the issue. Thank you. Regarding the .get() inside a task, the chaining is good if you have a small context to exchange between each worker. In my case I have a worker with a big context. The get is only required to know if the worker should continue to work on this big task or not. This is a workaround as it is not possible to cancel a ongoing task with celery. Do you have any better suggestion to be compliant with 3.2?

Comment: I mostly use chain of tasks with immutable signature. You can use signals for your case. See updated method.

Comment: Thank you but I really don't know how to handle a stop command to your big_task. My understanding from your celery link is that I should save the context in `memcached` and cut the big task in small one chained. In my case, cutting the big task is very difficult to setup. Do you have another suggestion to setup a simple stop command?

Comment: If you are just worried about stopping tasks, you can use chain. Added a simple example to stop chain.

Comment: Thank you but regarding the doc revoke can't be use programmatically ( http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#revoke-revoking-tasks). The solution seems to be less cleaner than a task call in a task.

Comment: @ChillarAnand if we return python dictionary instead of JSON does it still work? Or does the get() keeps on waiting on celery client side?

Comment: It should work with the python dictionary also. @sattva_venu

Comment: @ChillarAnand, I am running a long running celery task on remote Windows host which takes around 2 hours. After it completes the celery worker doesn't reply back to client. Can you let me know how to debug this. And when I press enter on the celery worker command prompt, it shows connection reset error.